# rspec + webkit is losing session/cookie after first request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webkit, capybara, capybara-webkit

using rspec with the default driver is working fine and all tests are passed.

changing `driver: :webkit` will have a bad side-effect.

1. step: the user is logged in
2. step: visiting root_path **with** a session (current_user)
3. step: visiting root_path **without a session** (current_user = nil)

so either after the first `visit root_path` or before the second, the session is killed or whatever - we can't get the user to stay logged in.

test looks like this

```
scenario 'something', driver: :webkit do
  user = FactoryGirl.create :user
  login_as(user)
  visit root_path
  visit root_path
end
```

is this a known bug? are there any workarounds or are we missing something ?

---

as requested:

```
 def login_as(user)
    visit root_path
    click_on "Login"
    fill_in "user[login]", with: user.username
    fill_in "user[password]", with: user.password
    click_on "Sign in"
  end
```

Comment: How are you implementing login_as?

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: How do you know the login is actually working?  There's no check anywhere in the code you're showing that after the visits they have any specific content on them? It's possible you're actually triggering the visit root_path before the submit for login has even occurred, which would cancel the login.   Try adding something like   expect(page).to have_content('You are now logged in')  (or whatever text would be shown after a successful login) after the login_as step (or as the last step of the login_as method)

Comment: well, defenitely logged in. if i call `visit root_path` the first time and then say `save_and_opeǹ`im defenitely logged in. also the login-specs (using exactly the same method and then expecting some code on the page to make sure the login is working) is green. as i said before, with the *default webdriver* all tests are *green*. if we switch to webkit, they are losing session/or/cookie

Comment: The default driver runs everything synchronously --- drivers that use real browsers and support javascript do not necessarily do things synchronously - so it's possible in drivers other than rack-test for click_on 'Sign in'  to return immediately.  Therefore if you're not checking for content that would be seen on success the next visit root_path can get executed immediately and cancel the submission of the login form.  If that is not happening then the only place (given your sample code) that can be logging the user out is your own app

Comment: ill give a try tmrw and let you know. need to sleep now

Comment: ok - I'll add it as an answer rather than just a comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90860/discussion-between-huan-son-and-tom-walpole).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default driver runs everything synchronously --- drivers that use real browsers and support javascript do not necessarily do things synchronously - so it's possible in drivers other than rack-test for click_on 'Sign in' to return immediately. Therefore if you're not checking for content that would be seen on success the next visit root_path can get executed immediately and cancel the submission of the login form. To fix that add something like

```
expect(page).to have_content('You are now logged in') # whatever text is shown on a successful login
```

as the last line of your login_as method.  This is not normally an issue for most people, because after logging in the next step is usually to click on something on the page, which will make Capybara wait for that item to appear thereby waiting for the login to complete.

If that is not what is happening here then the only place (given your sample code) that can be logging the user out is your own app

Comment: well, so this is the actual real test. http://pastie.org/10449353 i dont use any other functions now, just straight everything. and this is the result. the first is as like the test, the second is with `driver: :webkit` . that can't be real O.o he is not able to login the user. but i dont know why :D

Comment: console output: http://pastie.org/10449356 is my testlogic stupid or is this seriously a webkit problem ?

Comment: Ok - so login is failing when using :webkit as the driver --  this is usually because of using transaction based database clearing.  You can't use transaction based database testing with the JS drivers because the app runs in a different thread than the test code and each has its own DB connection which means the user you're creating isn't actually visible to the app.  See https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example  -- you would have to change it from changing behavior on js: true to the driver metadata with the way you're specifying tests

Comment: i'll try it soon and let you know

Comment: yup, its a DBCleaner problem. thanks. i'm sure, now we can fix this. u saved us!

Answer (score 0):

if you are deleting the session after the first visit, it is expected that the user logout.

Does visiting without session means that visiting the page as anonymous?

Comment: well, the user is logged in. there is no way, that a regular pagevisit is killing the session. as i said, its working with the default driver, not with webkit :(

Comment: and yes, not having a session (or a cookie) means you are not logged in and don't have full access